# How to use a variable for the rotation function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an element every second by a certain amount using transform:rotate()  but I can't figure out how to use a variable for the rotation instead of a string.

I tried making a concatenation function as well as concatenating inside the rotate function itself

```
        function runTime() {

            var d = new Date();
            var s = s+6
            var m = m+.1
            var h = h+.008333
            $("#seconds").css({'transform':'rotate('+s+'deg)'});
            $("#minutes").css({'transform':'rotate('+m+'deg)'});
            $("#hours").css({'transform':'rotate('+h+'deg)'});
            t=setTimeout(runTime,1000);

        }
```

Comment: The `hours` `minutes` `seconds` will always yeild the same value so it that an expected behavior?? If not then you should pass those values while you are preforming the recursive call using setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have jquery to verify, but your code should work.

- Ensure your `s`, `m`, and `h` variables are numerics as opposed to strings, otherwise adding `s+6` will concatenate as oppose to add.
- You can use `setInterval(runTime, 1000)` once as opposed to `setTimeout` each iteration
- You can use string templates e.g. `` `rotate(${h}deg` `` to make your css properties easier to read.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

let runTime = () => {
  let d = new Date();
  let s = d.getSeconds() * 6;
  let m = d.getMinutes() * 6
  let h = d.getHours() * 30;
  $("#seconds").style.transform = `rotate(${s}deg)`;
  $("#minutes").style.transform = `rotate(${m}deg)`;
  $("#hours").style.transform = `rotate(${h}deg)`;
}

setInterval(runTime, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

#hours {
  width: 3px;
  height: 26px;
}

#minutes {
  width: 2px;
  height: 30px;
}

#seconds {
  width: 1px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="seconds"></div>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="hours"></div>
```

Comment: Defining the variables from the the Date variable worked just fine thank you.